# Is there an up-to-date listing of current builds for each Windows Insider Preview ring?

Tags: windows-10, windows-insider

I'd like to know what the current build numbers (and changelog, ideally) are for the fast, slow, and release preview rings.

When I google, all I find are Microsoft's blog posts announcing each release, but it's difficult to sort through them all to find the latest build for each ring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't provide such a way to track the releases. There is a 3rd party site called [changewindows](http://changewindows.org/) which tracks Builds for Desktop and Mobile. It also tries to list changes.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that info. Is there a place to get those data regularly? As I said, combing through the blog is difficult.

Comment: what is too complicated by checking a website. Sorry, but I have no idea why this is such an issue for you. I do this and get info about any new build.

Comment: Perhaps you've found a better workflow? Here's mine: 1) Go to https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/ 2) Filter by PC. 3) Scroll through all posts looking for announcements. 4) Open each one and look for the ring to which it pertains. 5) Keep going until finding the latest post for each ring. At the moment, this takes me to page 3 before finding the current slow release, and I still haven't found an answer for the release preview ring. Compare [Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar) or [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases), which each take ten seconds on one page.

Comment: use RSS feed of the site and look in title if it includes announcements. This is what I do.

Comment: So in other words, no, there isn't a simple display of them like I asked about. I guess that's an answer.

Comment: I did some googling and found this page which shows the current build on the right site: http://changewindows.org/ In the feed I see that Build 14332 is now released in Fast Ring

Comment: That's just what I needed. Actually, it's even better! Thanks. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: @P1h3r1e3d13 I've updated the answer with the new link.